# jQuery not loading on

Tags: php, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have a jQuery fadetoggle function that's supposed to work on all eight pages of my site, but of the eight, the function only works on the home page and the Contacts page.

There are eight main pages on the site, seven of which are linked in the top navbar:

- Services Portfolio FAQ Tools News  About Contact

When the "Tools" link is clicked, this script is supposed fadeToggle the "#clients_button_container" div:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#clients_button').click(function() {
        $('#clients_button_container').fadeToggle('slow')
    });
});
</script>
```

Why is the script only working on the home page and the Contacts page, but none of the others? All pages are php instances.

Comment: where you placed this code

Comment: Looking at the console, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fadeToggle'`. [Learn how to debug JavaScript code](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Also this is relevant for this type of question: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You are also using the HTML 5 doctype, but then using the font tag in your menu. That's soooo HTML 3.2...

Comment: Felix: Noted and removed the link, thanks.
Revent: I'll change that over to CSS, forgot about that. :)

Comment: Removing the link does not make the question better though, because without context it is impossible to actually help you. You really have to debug the code on your own, as suggested in the linked question. Anyways, I hope the answer you got here helps you nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with jquery-1.9.1.min.js you are also loading jquery-1.2.6.min.js via AJAX towards the end of the pages `.fadeToggle()` doesn't work in.

So on those pages you are loading a recent version of jQuery, then loading an older version, which takes precedence (`.fadeToggle()` was added in 1.4.4).

Comment: Many thanks winter, didn't notice that I was still loading 1.2.6.

Comment: You should create a separate, consistent template for all your CSS and script file tags to avoid issues like this.